# Deploying Yeoman to heroku, site returns error: Cannot GET /

Tags: angularjs, node.js, heroku, yeoman

So i am trying to deploy my yeoman angular fullstack to heroku, but when i try to go onto the site, it just display: Cannot GET/

Ive tried everything i could find online, but everyone else who gets this error, seems to have made dozens of changes to the auto generated application.

My application just the auto generated from yeoman, the only thing i have added is an auto generated backend and route to work on, i have added a procfile for heroku, and i have changed my mongo URI to mlab.

I have also tried removing Dist from my git ignore.

Here is a git link you can clone if you want to check anything in the code:
https://github.com/nordtorp95/tempRepo

Answer (score 0):

I figured this problem out. What i did was to move into the dist folder before creating the heroku app, then i made an empty Procfile and pushed the folder to the heroku repo.